# Ember js pushObject overriding the array

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am working on Ember.js
and i have a select element which is set to send value "onchange" i am receiving the value without any problem ..
But i want to save every selection into an array and display it on the fly in labels
Here is my template.hbs

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select name="services" id="services" class="form-control" onchange={{action 'setValue' value="target.value"}}>
          <option> Select Services </option>
        {{#each services as |service|}}
          <option value="{{service.name}}">{{service.name}}</option>
        {{/each}}
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{selectedService}}
      {{#each selectedService as |selection index|}}
        <span class="label label-primary">{{index}} {{selection}}</span>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  </div>
```

and here is my controller

```
  actions: {
setValue(ser){
  var selectedService = [];
  this.set('selectedService', ser);
  selectedService.pushObject(ser);

  console.log(selectedService);
}
```

i tried to log "selectedService[1]" and select two items but it's not working it keeps on overriding the first item :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason with your case is you are constantly setting the `selectedService` to a new array. Instead of that; you need to get the `selectedService` of the controller and push to it. I mean the following:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  selectedService: [],

    actions: {
      setValue(ser){
        this.get('selectedService').pushObject(ser);
      }
    }
});
```

You initialize the `selectedService` once for the controller and can constantly push to the same array.

Can you please check the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/3c4b2734fa0dadfab477a9c5b98a9fa2?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C), I guess this is close to what you want.

Comment: still gives me an error "ReferenceError: selectedService is not defined" it's been 2 hours .. i hate programming :(

Comment: i will prepare a twiddle for you. do not give up!

Comment: i'd be thankful to you .. i'll be waiting .. Thanks a lot 

Comment: can you check the twiddle I have provided.

Comment: It worked .. thanks , thanks a lot .. now i love programming 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141644/discussion-between-haboosh-and-alptugd).